# Aggregate Postgresql rows into groups based on interval

Tags: postgresql

I have a result set from a CTE that returns the interval between each row insertion like follows:

| row | interval |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 0 mins 16.0 secs |
| 2 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 45 mins 42.0 se |
| 3 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 20.0 sec |
| 4 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 5 hours 4 mins 19.0 sec |
| 5 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 32.0 sec |
| 6 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 25.0 sec |
| 7 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 9.0 secs |
| 8 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 25.0 sec |
| 9 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 16.0 sec |
| 10 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 2 hours 50 mins 24.0 s |
| 11 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 6 mins 49.0 se |
| 12 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 4 mins 6.0 sec |
| 13 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 6.0 sec |
| 14 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 5 mins 48.0 se |
| 15 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 3 mins 42.0 se |
| 16 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 22.0 se |
| 17 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 30.0 se |
| 18 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 19.0 se |
| 19 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 16.0 se |
| 20 | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 55.0 se |

What I need to extract is an aggregation of all rows after a cut off value to be grouped together until another cut off initiates a new grouping. For example, say the interval cut off is 1 hour, I want (starting with row 1) rows 1-3 to be grouped together because row 1 is above the cut off and would be the beginning a new grouping. 2&3 would be included the group as well because they are below the cut off. At row 4 a new group would be created because 4 is above the cut off. Then all subsequent rows would be included up to 9. 10 would be its own group because 11 is also above the cutoff and so on.
Thanks very much for any assistance.

```
insert into tmp (x, delta)
values  (1, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 0 mins 16.0 secs'),
        (2, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 45 mins 42.0 secs'),
        (3, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 20.0 secs'),
        (4, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 4 mins 19.0 secs'),
        (5, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 32.0 secs'),
        (6, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 25.0 secs'),
        (7, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 9.0 secs'),
        (8, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 25.0 secs'),
        (9, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 16.0 secs'),
        (10, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 2 hours 50 mins 24.0 secs'),
        (11, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 1 hours 6 mins 49.0 secs'),
        (12, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 4 mins 6.0 secs'),
        (13, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 6.0 secs'),
        (14, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 5 mins 48.0 secs'),
        (15, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 3 mins 42.0 secs'),
        (16, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 22.0 secs'),
        (17, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 30.0 secs'),
        (18, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 19.0 secs'),
        (19, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 16.0 secs'),
        (20, '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 55.0 secs');
```

Comment: If every interval is 10 minutes, should all of the rows be grouped together, or should they end up in groups of 6?

Comment: Thanks Blue Star. I have added clarity to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me from your question if 10 consecutive rows with a delta of 10 minutes each should be lumped into one group or two. If you want them all to be one group, you can do something like this:

```sql
WITH ranges AS (
    SELECT x as start, lead(x) over (order by x) as end 
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE delta > interval '1 hour'
) 
SELECT ranges.start, string_agg(x::text, ', ') 
FROM tmp, ranges 
WHERE tmp.x >= ranges.start 
AND (ranges.end is null OR tmp.x < ranges.end)
GROUP BY ranges.start, ranges.end
ORDER BY ranges.start;

 start |               string_agg
-------+----------------------------------------
     1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    10 | 10
    11 | 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

First we identify the rows with a delta greater than the cutoff value, which represent the cutoff points, and we use a window function to determine the range. Then it's just a matter of aggregating over those ranges.

However, if you want the groups to be no more than one hour long, then that's trickier. I'm not sure if it can be done without a loop.

Comment: Hi Blue Star. Nailed it. I've slightly modified it, but only cosmetically.